# Memory profiling for a daemon process

Tags: c++, eclipse, memory, valgrind, profiler

I have a daemon process on which I want to perform a memory profile. So I took valgrind as a choice and ran it using massif tool, but since the process never dies, massif never returns the output file. Even I try to send a TERM signal to the process, I am not receiving any output from massif.

So now I tried installing a plugin of valgrind in my eclipse and started trying to run the profile on an already created binary of my daemon process, but when I start the profiler, it says 2 kinds of errors:

1. failing saying not able to load a library. I didn't find any way to set the library path in the profile configuration.
2. failing bad permissions to read a memory address.

So I am not even able to run the profiler in eclipse.

I tried gdb, I tried getting the memory info, but that is what "/proc//maps" would give. So of no use.

Finally here is my use case:

1. I have a daemon process that never quits and I want to perform memory profiling on it.
2. I want to get snapshots of no of memory allocations happened, max memory allocations, which instruction is trying to allocate the most number of allocations etc etc.
3. Better if I could get a visual interface for the memory profiling so that I can even share it with my manager.

So please suggest me is there any such profiler that helps and any pointers to where to get the documentation etc.

Thanks in Advance!
Vinay.

Answer (score 0):

When running your program under valgrind, various commands
(depending on the tool) can be executed from the shell, using
vgdb in standalone mode.

When running with --tool=massif, you can do on demand snapshot, while
your program is running.

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.valgrind-monitor-commands for more information.